# Find if there is a number in an array that appears more than n/8 times

Tags: arrays, algorithm, select, data-structures, time-complexity

The question is:

Describe an algorithm that find in O(n) time if there is in an array of n numbers,a number that appears more than n/8 times.

Now I have the answer which is:

We'll do Select for the numbers in places: n/9,2*n/9,3*n/9,...,8*n/9 , and than check if one of those 8 candidates appears at least n/8 times.

But I don't understand why would this algorithm work.

For example,consider the following array:
[3,3,1,3,2,3,4,3,5,3,6,3,7,3,8,3,9,3].

So here n=18, and if for this algorithm the candidates would be 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9 and when we'll check if these numbers appear at least n/8 times the answer will be no,but actually for 3 the answer would be yes.

So I don't understand why is this algorithm correct...

Comment: Only makes sense if the repeats are adjacent.

Comment: Could you help me find a correct algorithm?

Comment: This is a *homework question,* isn't it? Like you, I see no reason why the "answer" that you have would actually work, *unless,* perhaps, the vector was known to be **sorted.** I hope that you have a well-thumbed copy of Dr. Djikstra's *Sorting and Searching* on your nearby bookshelf ...

Comment: This is a question from an old exam,and that was the official answer for that question.

Answer (score 0):

The key insight here is that Select, especially when capitalised, has a special meaning: it references the problem of finding the kth largest entry in an unsorted array. Perhaps somewhat surprisingly a priori, this can be done in linear time, for example using a median-of-5 pivoting strategy in combination with the QuickSelect algorithm. So if you Select-with-an-uppercase-S the n/9, 2n/9, ... entries (cost: 9*linear - which is linear), you definitely find any entries that occur n/8 times. Then iterate through your array again to count the number of occurrences of each of these candidates, and presto you're done.